# How to get response message from web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following web controller:

```
List<string> output = new List<string>();
output.Add("line1");
output.Add("line2");
output.Add("line3");
output.Add("line4");

using (var memorystream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memorystream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        var fileInArchive = archive.CreateEntry("entry1");
        using (var entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
        {
            output.ForEach(streamWriter.WriteLine);
        }
    }

    memorystream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(memorystream.GetBuffer())
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = 
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "test.zip"
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
    return result;
}
```

On the receiving end i have a c# web form that access the controller this way:

```
var responsebody = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;

string filename = "test.zip";

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader(
            "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", filename));
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(responsebody.ToArray());
```

But I just get an array of bytes in the reponsebody var. How can I convert this back to the original type, which is a ziparchive, or just another binary file to have it more generic?

Comment: the byte array *is* the original type... what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: ... as a side note, use `await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync()` rather than calling `.Result`

Comment: If you want to create an instance `of ZipArchive` you do it the same way you did in the controller but use the `MemoryStream` constructor that takes a byte array.

Comment: Hi Alex, why should I use await instead of .result? My method is not async, so I get an error on that. I can make a new method, but what is the use here?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I convert this back to the original type, which is a
>   `ZipArchive`?

You sent back the `byte[]` as the response. That means, that on the receiving end, you'll have to exactly reverse that same process. Meaning, you take the byte array and put it into a `ZipArchive`, and start reading:

```
var bytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

using (var zippedBytesStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zippedBytesStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read, true))
{
    foreach (ZipEntry entry in archive.Entries)
    {
       // Do stuff with entry.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Yuval, thanks, that makes sense (still using .Result though instead of await). I copied your answer, but I get an error. Can you please doublecheck if the controller code should work with your client piece? The error I get upon foreach (ZipEntry entry in archive.Entries) is "Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.". Looks like the content of the stream does not match the type on the clientside (ziparchive or zipentry).

Comment: @Ronald How big is your zip file? That error is generated when you zip file is corrupt.

Comment: Hi, as you can see in the controller code, it is a ziparchive with just 1 entry containing 4 small text lines. The memory stream on the server side is 130 bytes. The byte array on the receiving end is 278 bytes. But I think these should match?

Comment: @Ronald Change `Content = new ByteArrayContent(memorystream.GetBuffer()` to `Content = new ByteArrayContent(memorystream.ToArray());`

Comment: Hi Yuval, thanks for your response, same error =(  alltough I now get 156 bytes returned (was 278). But still no luck

Comment: Hi Yuval, your code definitely works. But when I use it split over a controller and a client part (two different c# projects) it does not fly. Any idea? Can I use the memorystream.ToArray anyway? Does it parse the entire stream content (in fact the complete ziparchive) to the caller? Can you share an example with controller and consumer? Thanks!